# IIS won't bind to SSL Certificiate?

Tags: ssl, iis-7, ssl-certificate

We had to replace the certificate our application was using because it was expired. However now when you browse to the HTTPS site we get "This page can't be displayed". The SSL certificate is working fine, and we do have the private key for it. We are running IIS version 7.0

Comment: Run a report and the cause should be clear https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: What browser are you using? Have you tried using other browser when accessing https site? Is your SSL set on the same site, if not, you can refer to this link: [The page cannot be displayed](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/260096/page-cannot-be-displayed-when-you-connect-through-ssl).

Comment: I ran the SSL diagnostic tool and got Error : PrivateKey.KeyExchangeAlgorithm PrivateKey.KeySize Keyset does not exist, which seems to indicate an issue with the the private keys not being accessible to IIS

Comment: It will probably be a permissions problem on the certificate, you will need to set the appropriate permissions on the private key to allow that service account access to it.